# Gmail API query to retrieve unread messages sent after given time

Tags: javascript, gmail, gmail-api

I am using gmail api to programatically retrieve email messages (using javascript) which are:
1. unread
2. sent after a given time

I know the query for retrieving unread messages is : 'is:unread'
and the query for retrieving messages sent after a particular date is 'in:sent after : yyyy/mm/dd'

But How do we combine the above two queries into a single query?

Also, if there is any documentation for the queries for searching messages supported by gmail api, please share the same - I don't seem to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
query = is:unread OR (is:sent AND after:<TIME_IN_SECONDS_SINCE_EPOCH>)
```

Let's say you wanted unread or sent messages after Fri, 04 Jan 2013 07:00:00 GMT, you would write:

```
query = is:unread OR (is:sent AND after:1357282800)

GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=is%3Aunread+OR+(is%3Asent+AND+after%3A1357282800)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

The query is identical to the search bar in the Gmail Client, so anything you can find in the [Advanced search documentation](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) works, even though some things (like the seconds since epoch-query above) are undocumented.